# How does this change affect the speed of this database query?

Tags: mysql, database, django, optimization

First I was using this request:

```
Model.object.get(name='something', date=somedatavariable)
```

But then I needed to extend my query and change it to this:

```
Model.objects.get(name__icontains="something", date__range(start_date,end_date))
```

Suddenly my database takes 5 times longer than with the original query. What's going on here, and how can I make it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case-insensitive wildcard search (`name__icontains='something'`) will DEFINITELY be a more expensive DB query than a case-sensitive exact match (`name='something'`). 5 times slower doesn't sound unreasonable, and it will vary heavily based on any and all of the following:

- Database Engine (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc.)
- Number of records in the DB
- Volume of text in each name field that it has to search through
- Whether or not there's an appropriate index the DB can use for that column

The last one there is very tricky. Doing full-text indexing for a database is very hard to get right, very easy to get wrong, and not even supported by all database engines.

The same goes for `date` vs. `date__range`: you're using a quick, simple, easy-to-index exact match in one, and an inexact match in the other.

The bottom line: if you don't need inexact matches, then don't use them. They're expensive DB operations and WILL take significantly longer.

Comment: Maybe I can somehow reconfigure MySQL DB. I dont like how it work. I think pretty long time. But in Task Manager it show that MySQL use only 25 mb. Can I extend my memory for MsSQL?

Comment: It's not a memory issue. MySQL's memory-management is fine. You need to understand more about how database indexing and collation work. Or for a quick "I don't want to understand, just give me a solution..." then I recommend this Google search: http://www.google.com/search?q=django+mysql+full-text+indexing

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if anyone can guess, how exactly your database behaved :-) But you can use this middleware:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/161/

and check, what kind of sql queries were made and how much time they took.

Comment: Knowing exactly how long the queries took is a good thing, though honestly I prefer to do that kind of profiling in a unit test where I can isolate variables. What the queries look like is fairly straightforward, though, and the root of the OP's slowdown is pretty clear.